# When to release camera properly when using multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera

in my android project, i am using a camera instance to take pictures. When taken a picture, i will start a new activity. Right now i am releasing the camera in onPause and re-creating it in onResume. This works properly. Now my problem is; when going back to the camera-activity from some other activity, it will take a "long" time. I understand that this i because of the recreating of the camera.

I believe that this problem is solved by not releasing the camera before the user actually closes the application.

So my question is:
When do i release my camera in a sane way, and/or how is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to release your `Camera` instance on `onPause` method of the class, in which you open the camera. Because, take the below example:

Let you open the `Camera` in `Activity`, let say `Activity1`. Now you navigate to other `Activity`, let say `Activity2`. Now due to any reason, your application crashes. Now you can't release your `Camera` instance and no new instance can be created.

OR

User navigates to `Activity2` and press home button and then `Force Stops` the application from `Settings`. In this condition also the `Camera` instance can't be released.

No method of `Activity1` is called in above 2 conditions.

So you should release your `Camera` object in `onPause` of `Activity1`

Hope I am clear.

Comment: This is just as u suspected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

according to Android [Camera reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html):

> Important: Call release() to release the camera for use by other
>   applications. Applications should release the camera immediately in
>   onPause() (and re-open() it in onResume()).